# How do product designers experience onboarding?

Tags: experience, onboarding

It's very important to play around and experience a feature in the wild for iterative process. Once you've designed onboarding which includes getting started tooltips and emails, it's difficult to experience it as a new user. How do designers experience onboarding themselves? Do they create a bunch of email ids and sign up and then wait to see what emails and tooltips they see? That sounds very cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it's a biased experience for the creator of the feature as they are not only familiar with it but it matches their mental model of the product. user testing on onboarding must be done on users who weren't involved in the creation of the product or it's features. also its better that these users are not in the industry of ui design or tech.

Comment: But what if I just wanted to test it myself or if QA is trying to test onboarding? What would be the way to simplify this testing process without having to create new email-ids and having to wait for onboarding emails?

Comment: go to a cafe and show a prototype to someone to get their feedback in exchange for a coffee

Comment: The role of QA is just to test that it works and is fit for purpose.If you are just using emails for your onboarding then I don't think you are really using onboarding to its full potential.

Comment: You can programatically automate the email creation for testing purposes to improve the process of testing. It will not be easy but it will save you a lot of time in the future. Automated Testing is a specialist QA skill and while it works really well for certain things, it does have some limitations.

Comment: @Splatz yes, I think the end solution will require creating a custom app.

Answer (score 0):

As a Designer, we are designing for an intended user experience, and because of this, we can never experience this like a real user who encounters it for the first time.

You really need to perform usability testing with real users to capture how they feel about the solution.